# performant python code, for the combination of 10 digit numbers

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pthreads

I would like to know if this code, see below, can be accelerated.
I'm not sure but could the library "thread" help, or something similar?

Can this task be split up so that it is completed in less than 3 minutes?
at the moment the process takes more than 10 minutes

Information about the code, the code creates all possible combinations of all 10 digit numbers

Code

```
#import sys

start_number=10
end_number=start_number

# Define the minimum and maximum number of digits
min_digits = int(start_number)
max_digits = int(end_number)

# Define the output file name
output_file = "number_wordlist_10.txt"

# Generate and write numbers to the file
with open(output_file, "w") as file:
    for num_digits in range(min_digits, max_digits + 1):
        start_range = 10**(num_digits - 1)
        end_range = (10**num_digits) - 1
        for number in range(start_range, end_range + 1):
            file.write(str(number) + "\n")

print(f"Wordlist has been generated and saved to {output_file}")
```